# Design a counter with a count sequence using Verilog

Tags: verilog, bit

Design a counter with a count sequence based on your ID number as follows: write down your student ID, append two 0’s and then append your ID with each digit incremented modulo 10. For example if your student ID is **27273289**, then the count sequence is **272732890038384390** and then back to the start. Implement your design with **at most 5 flip-flops** using Verilog on a DE2 board. Show the result on a **7 segment display using HEX**. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 flip-flops implies 32 states. Your sequence `272732890038384390` is 19 long.

Build a state machine which counts from 0 to 18, looping back to 0 on completion.

Then use a look up table (combinatorial logic) to decode state into an output value.

Update question with code if you get stuck, then we can help with the programming problem.